# How to Integrate Jasper Report Integration 2.3.0 with Oracle Apex 5.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Hy!!

I Want to Integrate Jasper Report Integration 2.3.0 with Oracle Apex 5.1 according to Given Installation in Jasper Report Integration Index Page but not. There are some following issues that i am facing after Installation Please guide that Solution ..

[image: The Upper Checks 1,2,3 are showing "All tests Passed"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it is the security in Oracle DB on UTL_HTTP.  You have to allow access to destinations, in your case your JasperReport URL.  Here is 1 link that describes allowing web resource access. https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11520.calling-web-pages-and-web-services-from-the-oracle-database

Here is the core of the article:

---

If you just want to read the content of a web page with HTTP, you can use the UTL_HTTP package.
Allowing Access

The database does not allow calls to any address a developer fancies; you need to set up an Access Control List (ACL) first. There are two steps: Create an ACL, and add a host and port range to the ACL.

To allow access to e.g. www.oracle.com, you could use the following:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.create_acl (
    acl          => 'acl_oracle',
    description  => 'Allow access to oracle.com for testing',
    principal    => 'SCOTT',
    is_grant     => TRUE,
    privilege    => 'connect',
    start_date   => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    end_date     => NULL);
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.assign_acl (
    acl => 'acl_oracle',
    host => 'www.oracle.com',
    lower_port => 80,
    upper_port => NULL);
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff Leach... For Giving Some Help